# C++ compiler does not see overload constructor

Tags: c++

I'm adding a new constructor to [GPD](https://github.com/atenpas/gpd), but the compiler simply does not see it. The new constructor is defined in the header file, and the implementation is trivial (changing from initialization using util::ConfigFile to read files to initialization using arguments passed in).

header file

```
class GraspDetector {
 public:
  GraspDetector(const std::string &config_filename);

  GraspDetector(const candidate::HandGeometry &hand_geom,
                bool &plot_normals, bool &plot_samples,
                bool &plot_candidates, bool &plot_filtered_candidates,
                bool &plot_valid_grasps, bool &plot_clustered_grasps,
                bool &plot_selected_grasps,
                const candidate::CandidatesGenerator::Parameters &generator_params,
                const candidate::HandSearch::Parameters &hand_search_params,
                const descriptor::ImageGeometry &image_geom,
                const std::string &model_file, const std::string &weights_file,
                const int &device, const int &batch_size, const int &min_score,
                bool &remove_plane, const std::vector<double> &workspace_grasps,
                const double &min_aperture, const double &max_aperture,
                bool &filter_approach_direction,
                const std::vector<double> &approach_direction,
                const double &thresh_rad, const int &min_inliers,
                const int &num_selected);
...
```

cpp file

```
GraspDetector::GraspDetector(const candidate::HandGeometry &hand_geom,
                             bool &plot_normals, bool &plot_samples,
                             bool &plot_candidates, bool &plot_filtered_candidates,
                             bool &plot_valid_grasps, bool &plot_clustered_grasps,
                             bool &plot_selected_grasps,
                             const candidate::CandidatesGenerator::Parameters &generator_params,
                             const candidate::HandSearch::Parameters &hand_search_params,
                             const descriptor::ImageGeometry &image_geom,
                             const std::string &model_file, const std::string &weights_file,
                             const int &device, const int &batch_size, const int &min_score,
                             bool &remove_plane, const std::vector<double> &workspace_grasps,
                             const double &min_aperture, const double &max_aperture,
                             bool &filter_approach_direction,
                             const std::vector<double> &approach_direction,
                             const double &thresh_rad, const int &min_inliers,
                             const int &num_selected) {

  Eigen::initParallel();

  std::cout << hand_geom;

  // Read plotting parameters.
  plot_normals_ = plot_normals;
  plot_samples_ = plot_samples;
  plot_candidates_ = plot_candidates;
  plot_filtered_candidates_ = plot_filtered_candidates;
  plot_valid_grasps_ = plot_valid_grasps;
  plot_clustered_grasps_ = plot_clustered_grasps;
  plot_selected_grasps_ = plot_selected_grasps;
  printf("============ PLOTTING ========================\n");
  printf("plot_normals: %s\n", plot_normals_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("plot_samples %s\n", plot_samples_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("plot_candidates: %s\n", plot_candidates_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("plot_filtered_candidates: %s\n",
         plot_filtered_candidates_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("plot_valid_grasps: %s\n", plot_valid_grasps_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("plot_clustered_grasps: %s\n",
         plot_clustered_grasps_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("plot_selected_grasps: %s\n",
         plot_selected_grasps_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("==============================================\n");

  // Create object to generate grasp candidates.
  candidates_generator_ = std::make_unique<candidate::CandidatesGenerator>(
      generator_params, hand_search_params);

  printf("============ CLOUD PREPROCESSING =============\n");
  printf("voxelize: %s\n", generator_params.voxelize_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("voxel_size: %.3f\n", generator_params.voxel_size_);
  printf("remove_outliers: %s\n",
         generator_params.remove_statistical_outliers_ ? "true" : "false");
  printStdVector(generator_params.workspace_, "workspace");
  printf("sample_above_plane: %s\n",
         generator_params.sample_above_plane_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("normals_radius: %.3f\n", generator_params.normals_radius_);
  printf("refine_normals_k: %d\n", generator_params.refine_normals_k_);
  printf("==============================================\n");

  printf("============ CANDIDATE GENERATION ============\n");
  printf("num_samples: %d\n", hand_search_params.num_samples_);
  printf("num_threads: %d\n", hand_search_params.num_threads_);
  printf("nn_radius: %3.2f\n", hand_search_params.nn_radius_frames_);
  printStdVector(hand_search_params.hand_axes_, "hand axes");
  printf("num_orientations: %d\n", hand_search_params.num_orientations_);
  printf("num_finger_placements: %d\n",
         hand_search_params.num_finger_placements_);
  printf("deepen_hand: %s\n",
         hand_search_params.deepen_hand_ ? "true" : "false");
  printf("friction_coeff: %3.2f\n", hand_search_params.friction_coeff_);
  printf("min_viable: %d\n", hand_search_params.min_viable_);
  printf("==============================================\n");

  // Print grasp image parameters.
  std::cout << image_geom;

  // Read classification parameters and create classifier.
  // Device: eCPU = 0, eGPU = 1, eVPU = 2, eFPGA = 3
  if (!model_file.empty() || !weights_file.empty()) {
    classifier_ = net::Classifier::create(
        model_file, weights_file, static_cast<net::Classifier::Device>(device),
        batch_size);
    printf("============ CLASSIFIER ======================\n");
    printf("model_file: %s\n", model_file.c_str());
    printf("weights_file: %s\n", weights_file.c_str());
    printf("batch_size: %d\n", batch_size);
    printf("==============================================\n");
  }

  // Create object to create grasp images from grasp candidates (used for
  // classification).
  image_generator_ = std::make_unique<descriptor::ImageGenerator>(
      image_geom, hand_search_params.num_threads_,
      hand_search_params.num_orientations_, false, remove_plane);

  // Read grasp filtering parameters based on robot workspace and gripper width.
  workspace_grasps_ = workspace_grasps;
  min_aperture_ = min_aperture;
  max_aperture_ = max_aperture;
  printf("============ CANDIDATE FILTERING =============\n");
  printStdVector(workspace_grasps_, "candidate_workspace");
  printf("min_aperture: %3.4f\n", min_aperture_);
  printf("max_aperture: %3.4f\n", max_aperture_);
  printf("==============================================\n");

  // Read grasp filtering parameters based on approach direction.
  direction_ << approach_direction[0], approach_direction[1], approach_direction[2];
  thresh_rad_ = thresh_rad;

  // Read clustering parameters.
  clustering_ = std::make_unique<Clustering>(min_inliers);
  cluster_grasps_ = min_inliers > 0 ? true : false;
  printf("============ CLUSTERING ======================\n");
  printf("min_inliers: %d\n", min_inliers);
  printf("==============================================\n\n");

  // Read grasp selection parameters.
  num_selected_ = num_selected;

  // Create plotter.
  plotter_ = std::make_unique<util::Plot>(hand_search_params.hand_axes_.size(),
                                          hand_search_params.num_orientations_);
}
```

file error occured (grasp_detector_ is a declared pointer, if using the first constructor GraspDetector(const std::string &config_filename), compiles successfully):

```
  grasp_detector_ = new gpd::GraspDetector(hand_geom, plot_normals, plot_samples,
                                           plot_candidates, plot_filtered_candidates,
                                           plot_valid_grasps, plot_clustered_grasps,
                                           plot_selected_grasps,
                                           generator_params, hand_search_params,
                                           image_geom,
                                           model_file, weights_file,
                                           device, batch_size, min_score,
                                           remove_plane, workspace_grasps,
                                           min_aperture, max_aperture,
                                           filter_approach_direction,
                                           approach_direction,
                                           thresh_rad, min_inliers,
                                           num_selected);
```

Error:

```
/home/yiying/catkin_ws/src/gpd_ros/src/gpd_ros/grasp_detection_node.cpp:100:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘gpd::GraspDetector::GraspDetector(const gpd::candidate::HandGeometry&, bool&, bool&, bool&, bool&, bool&, bool&, bool&, gpd::candidate::CandidatesGenerator::Parameters&, gpd::candidate::HandSearch::Parameters&, gpd::descriptor::ImageGeometry&, const string&, const string&, const int&, const int&, const int&, bool&, const std::vector<double>&, const double&, const double&, bool&, const std::vector<double>&, const double&, const int&, const int&)’
                                            num_selected);
                                                        ^
In file included from /home/yiying/catkin_ws/src/gpd_ros/include/gpd_ros/grasp_detection_node.h:55:0,
                 from /home/yiying/catkin_ws/src/gpd_ros/src/gpd_ros/grasp_detection_node.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/gpd/grasp_detector.h:72:3: note: candidate: gpd::GraspDetector::GraspDetector(const string&)
   GraspDetector(const std::string &config_filename);
   ^
/usr/local/include/gpd/grasp_detector.h:72:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 25 provided
/usr/local/include/gpd/grasp_detector.h:66:7: note: candidate: gpd::GraspDetector::GraspDetector(gpd::GraspDetector&&)
 class GraspDetector {
       ^
/usr/local/include/gpd/grasp_detector.h:66:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 25 provided
```

/usr/local/include/gpd/grasp_detector.h:72:3 corresponds to GraspDetector(const std::string &config_filename).

/usr/local/include/gpd/grasp_detector.h:78:3 corresponds to constructor with 25 arguments

/usr/local/include/gpd/grasp_detector.h:66:7 corresponds to class GraspDetector

Comment: You have 24 too many parameters. That's a lot :-)

Comment: I'll be honest with you -- that is one of the worst abuses I have seen for a parameter list.  Quick and without looking, what does the eleventh parameter mean?

Comment: I know a better way -- create a single `struct` with members.  The client fills in that struct and passes that `struct` as a single argument.  Then not only is the code cleaned up, all of the problems of not finding the constructor more than likely gets cleared up to.

Comment: Consider passing `int` and `double` instead of `const int&` and `const double &`. Also, you may want to join all those `bool&` and other parameters into some class.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It looks like the error is in the code you don't show. Maybe the header file and the cpp file are not aligned. Or there are different declarations of your class. Or the ctor you want to use is hidden with an `#if`/`#ifdef`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was being lazy, but theoretically it should work, shouldn't it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll try and update here.

Comment: @WernerHenze I though of that but it just involves too much code. A  GPD library and gpd_ros library.

Comment: @yiying -- That's a strange way of being "lazy".  It takes *more* work to call your constructor, let alone remember what each parameter means, and then worry about if the arguments are in the right order, etc.  The real "lazy" way, and better way, would have been to create a struct, have the caller fill it in, and just pass that parameter to the function.  Then parameter order doesn't matter, the client is confident they filled the struct correctly, etc.

Comment: @yiying No, there is not much code required. Strip it down to an almost empty class GraspDetector with only the constructors and try to reproduce it with that [mcve]. And please read the informaton behind the link that I added.

Comment: Are you sure the path given in the error message (/usr/local/include/gpd/grasp_detector.h) is the one you are trying to use? My guess is you have more than one version of the header on your computer. (But also, I agree with the others: 25 parameters does not look like a good idea.)

Comment: @Tfry Glad to see your comment. The error occurred because the header files are old ones.  I forgot to install the GPD library after I add the constructor and rebuild it. With the library installed, the code I’m using the library complies successfully. Thank you for pointing the right direction.